# Bash: custom function in bash with sed issue

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, sed

I tried to add a custom bash function in .bashrc file after reading this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38072/how-can-i-save-the-last-command-to-a-file

I basically put

```
function getlast {
    fc -ln "$1" "$2" | sed '1s/^[[:space:]]*//'
}
```

inside .bashrc.

Notice that I've changed the command line from

```
fc -ln "$1" "$1"
```

to

```
fc -ln "$1" "$2"
```

So I can have more flexibility on using the fc command.

Now just

```
getlast
```

worked fine as it gave the last command I just typed.

However, when I tried to use it with two command line arguments like this:

```
getlast -1 -3
```

I got this error message which is basically sed help message:

```
sed: invalid option -- '1'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

-n, --quiet, --silent
             suppress automatic printing of pattern space
-e script, --expression=script
             add the script to the commands to be executed
-f script-file, --file=script-file
             add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed
--follow-symlinks
             follow symlinks when processing in place
 -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
             edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
  ......
```

When i just use fc -ln like this

```
fc -ln -1 -3
```

It worked fine... and it also works fine on the command line to have sed after fc. So I know it's probably something with bash...

I also tried to twist sed by removing 1 inside ' ' and other things but it didn't work. I don't understand why it doesn't work...Can someone help me understand the problem here?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

I tried to remove the sed part so in the function, there is just:

```
function getlast {
    fc -ln "$1" "$2"
}
```

And now `getlast` still works and `getlast -1 -3` still gave me that same error message even though there is no sed involved... so the problem might be something else? Really confused...

[EDIT2]

It works now. I'm not sure I understand what exactly was going on.

Basically, after reading NeronLeVelu's answer and trying so many things, I realized it might be the particular bash session that have this problem. So I opened a new window within tmux and tried `getlast -1 -2` and now it works... no more sed error...

Not sure what happened in the session I was working on.. but now it works.

Comment: Did you `source ~/.bashrc` after you added it? Does `type getlast` show the exact function definition you posted?

Comment: yeah, i did that as always.

Comment: you either do `function getlast {...}` or `getlast() {...}` nothing else

Comment: OK. changed that and still not working...

Answer (score 1):

try to add --posix and/or -e before the `'` after `sed`

```
function getlast() {
    fc -ln "$1" "$2" | sed --posix -e '1s/^[[:space:]]*//'
}
```

under AIX (so not GNU sed and --posix not allowed)

```
bash-3.2$      echo "with space before\n"
with space before

bash-3.2$ getlast -1 -2

getlast -1 -2
+ getlast -1 -2
+ set -vx
+ fc -ln -1 -2
+ sed -e '1s/^[[:space:]]*//'
echo "with space before"
         getlast -1 -2
```

Comment: I just add a session test, work here. What is your session error (including maybe a set -vx in your function like on my session)

Comment: OK. It works now. I added a new edit to explain what happened although I still don't quite understand it. Thanks for your answer and time!

Answer (score 0):

bash is not magic, so if you're getting an error message from sed, and the code you *think* you are running has no sed involved, it's obviously not the code you are *actually* running.  you can see the definition with

```
typeset -f getlast
```